# How to read needed files from rar archive directly to InputStream (without extracting whole archive)?

Tags: java, rar

Seems quite simple with zip archive using java.util.zip.ZipFile like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    final ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("C:/test.zip");

    final Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();

    while(entries.hasMoreElements())
    {
        final ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();

        if(entry.getName().equals("NEEDED_NAME"))
        {
            try(InputStream inputStream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry))
            {
                // Do what's needed with the inputStream.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the alternative for rar archives?

I'm aware of Junrar, but didn't found a way to do it without extracting whole archive to some folder.

Edit:

I have added "if sentence for entry.getName()" line just to indicate what I'm interested only in some specific files inside archive and would like to avoid extracting whole archive to some folder and later deleting those files.

Comment: Note that this code **will extract the zip** while you read it. It is impossible to "read without extracting". It just hides this fact from you.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm sill searching for alternative for rar then (without the need to explicitly extract to specific folder). It should do that job "under the curtains" as with zip example.

Comment: Also I can target only needed file with this code with entry.getName() and that's what I'm mostly trying to do. I will update the example a bit. It should be much faster than extracting whole archive.

Comment: RAR is not a standard file format, and there is no support in the core Java libraries for them. Look for a third-party RAR library

Comment: I am looking at third party libraries (like Junrar and others), but I don't see a way to do this without extracting whole archive to specific folder (which I don't need).

Answer (score 0):

I end up using something like this for now (with Junrar):

```
final Archive archive = new Archive(new File("C:/test.rar"), null);

final LocalFolderExtractor lfe = new LocalFolderExtractor(new File("/path/to/temp/location/"), new FileSystem());

for (final FileHeader fileHeader : archive)
{
    if(fileHeader.getFileNameString().equals("NEEDED_NAME"))
    {
         File file = null;

         try
         {
             file = lfe.extract(archive, fileHeader);

             // Create inputStream from file and do what's needed.
         }
         finally
         {
             // Fully delete the file + folders if needed.
         }
    }
}
```

Maybe there is a better way :)